# Docker image automatic increment tagging with semantic

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I have the following yml file for githubactions , and I need some guidance to auto increment the image tags, whenever a new commit is made or PR , how best can I do this ?

My current code, creates a tag of `0.0.1`, but I want the tag to begin with 1.0.0 with the `v` ofcourse at the beginning, `v1.0.0`.

Here's my snippet :

```
name: Deploy main branch to production

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev
    tags-ignore:
      - 'v*'

permissions:
  id-token: write
  checks: write
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write

env:
  AWS_REGION: "eu-central-1"
  ROLE_SESSION_NAME: "laas-api-deploy"
  ECR_REPOSITORY_URL: ${{ secrets.ECR_REPOSITORY_URL }}

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set initial version tag if none exist
        run: |
          if ! git describe --tags --abbrev=0 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
            git config user.email "actions@github.com"
            git tag v1.0.0
            git push origin v1.0.0
          fi
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Semantic versioning
        id: versioning
        uses: paulhatch/semantic-version@v5.1.0
        with:
          branch: dev
          tag_prefix: "v"
          major_pattern: "change:"
          minor_pattern: "feat:"
          format: "v${major}.${minor}.${patch}-prerelease{increment}"

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: aws_role ....
          role-session-name: role_session
          aws-region: my region

      - name: Build the Docker image
        run: |
          docker build -t ${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_URL }}:${{ steps.versioning.outputs.VERSION }} .

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Push the Docker image with Semver to Amazon ECR
        run: |
          docker push ${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_URL }}:${{ steps.versioning.outputs.VERSION }}
```

How best can I do the auto increment.